# About site design

Tags: petición-de-funcionalidad, diseño

I just noticed that other sites have a banner or different colors based on their site content, like the English SE. It is possible to do the same with Spanish SE?

---

**Proposal:** I suggest to make the banner with the signatures of the most importants writers of the Spanish Language, like Miguel de Cervantes:

[image]

Comment: A relevant post (on this meta) by one of our designers from last week: [Custom Spanish Language design and logo - Information gathering](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4448/30873) :)

Comment: Update: [New design launched](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4471/30873)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When Spanish.SE graduates, it will get a dedicated design. Until then, you're stuck with the [generic beta theme](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/the-new-stack-exchange-beta-theme-2/).

Reaching graduation represents a community achievement. But in order to remove the beta label, [we](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-managers-and-what-do-they-do) need to have confidence that a site is self-sustaining. One of the things we look at is the [question rate](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14456/spanish-language). When a site is able to sustain a strong rate of questions (and several other indicators of a strong community) it goes to our designers for a custom theme.

In the meantime, there are a few things you can do to improve the odds of graduation. One of my favorite ideas is a [weekly topic challenge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/). A small number of users working together on meta can spark new life in a site by committing themselves to asking questions is a specific tag or about a specific topic.

Comment: Now that the Beta label has been removed, will we be getting a dedicated design?

Comment: No, @ukemi. We are not Beta anymore, but getting a design is not straight forward nowadays when graduating. I see our site as a Beta without a Beta tag, since it is the only thing that changed.