# New design launched

Tags: discusión, diseño

As you can see, the new design just went live! At this point, we are done with major revisions to the design (although you can still report CSS/styling bugs by starting a new post and tagging it with [design](/questions/tagged/design) and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)). Thank you for your valuable feedback.

I have enjoyed working with you to create this theme. Thank you for being an awesome community, and I hope you enjoy the new design! Gracias a todos!

Comment: I like it, congratulations. I don't like the _¡!_, though, it is like a silent interjection that produces a mental blockage while trying to read it. I don't see it suggested in the various proposals that were given by the users in the [Site design and logo](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4451/1674) post.

Comment: The site looks better and more professional. Thank you for your hard work. While I don't think this was the most needed improvement for the site, having a better look probably will attract more users, get them to stay and participate more (asking more questions and voting more).